# Some child elements not hiding on $('#div').hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my div with lots of child elements:

```
<div class="text-center welcome">
    <!--<p class="lead">You haven't added any feeds. Click <a href=#>here</a> to browse them.</p>-->
    <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to Shopaholic</h1>
        <!-- Sign up container -->
        <div class="signup-container">
            <div id="output"></div>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <form id="signup-form" action="" method="POST">
                        <input name="signupEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="signupEmail" placeholder="Email address">
                        <input name="signupPassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="signupPassword" placeholder="Password">
                        <input name="signupPassword2" type="password" class="form-control" id="signupPassword2" placeholder="Password">
                        <select name="signupCountry" id="signupCountry" class="selectpicker">
                            <option value="0">Country</option>
                            <option value="United States">United States</option>
                            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option>Canada</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="signupGender" id="signupGender" class="selectpicker">
                            <option value="0">Gender</option>
                            <option value="f">Female</option>
                            <option value="m">Male</option>
                        </select>
                        <button id="signup" class="btn btn-success btn-block signup" type="submit">Sign up</button>
                    </form>
                    <p class="response-text" id="signup-response"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Login container -->
        <div class="login-container">
            <div id="output"></div>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <form id="login-form" action="" method="">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" placeholder="Email address">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Password">
                        <button id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block login">Log in</button>
                    </form>
                    <p class="response-text" id="login-response"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <p class="text-center"><a id="login_link" href=#>Already registered?</a><a id="signup_link" href=#>New user?</a></p>
    <p class="text-center" id="forgotten"><a href=#>Forgot your password?</a></p>
</div>
```

However, when I run `$('.welcome').hide();`, everything after the line that says `<!-- Login container -->` still shows. Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the closing `</div>` immediately preceding `<!-- Login container -->`; you're prematurely closing your `<div>` content. I looks like you've accidentally indented your code following the `<h1>` tag on line 2.

Correctly indented, you code should look like this:

```
<div class="text-center welcome">
    <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to Shopaholic</h1>
    <!-- Sign up container -->
    <div class="signup-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="form-box">
            <form id="signup-form" action="" method="POST">
                <input name="signupEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="signupEmail" placeholder="Email address">
                <input name="signupPassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="signupPassword" placeholder="Password">
                <input name="signupPassword2" type="password" class="form-control" id="signupPassword2" placeholder="Password">
                <select name="signupCountry" id="signupCountry" class="selectpicker">
                    <option value="0">Country</option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option>Canada</option>
                </select>
                <select name="signupGender" id="signupGender" class="selectpicker">
                    <option value="0">Gender</option>
                    <option value="f">Female</option>
                    <option value="m">Male</option>
                </select>
                <button id="signup" class="btn btn-success btn-block signup" type="submit">Sign up</button>
            </form>
            <p class="response-text" id="signup-response"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Login container -->
    <div class="login-container">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div class="form-box">
            <form id="login-form" action="" method="">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" placeholder="Email address">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Password">
                <button id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block login">Log in</button>
            </form>
            <p class="response-text" id="login-response"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="text-center"><a id="login_link" href=#>Already registered?</a><a id="signup_link" href=#>New user?</a></p>
    <p class="text-center" id="forgotten"><a href=#>Forgot your password?</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: @KimGysen, compare the code I've posted – it is correctly indented and depicts the correct `<div>` closures.

Comment: There was a sneaky `<div id="output"></div>` which opens and closes on the same line which I missed. With the current code, it's still showing the two `<p>` tags at the end.

Comment: Ah, sorted, there's one too many `</div>`s in `.login-container` too.

Comment: Just a note: you should not be using two divs with the same id. An id represents a unique identifier in the DOM...

Comment: Another note: a good ide will help you prevent these issues as they'll suggest closing your opening tags. I had trouble seeing the problem properly myself.

Comment: @Sebastian, the `<div id="output"></div>` should not materially affect anything (aside from indentation) since it closes immediately, but @KimGysen is correct – you should _not_ have multiple DOM elements on each page that share the same `id` attribute.

Comment: @Sebastian, what you said about the extra `<div>` is precisely what I've indicated in my answer. If this answer helped resolve your issue, please consider accepting it as correct.

Comment: I've accepted it - was just waiting for the timer to run out. Thanks for your help! Re `#output`, maybe I was unclear - it was the closing on the same line that meant that I missed it and added an extra `</div>` to 'close' it. I was talking about the extra div in `.login-container` - weren't you referring to `.signup-container`? There should be two in total as your script now shows.